# jQuery Ajax and setInterval Chrome Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to a return the value of a given URL periodically using jQuery and setInterval. My code looks like:

```
    $("form").submit(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#upload_progress').load('/upload_progress');
        }, 5000);
    });
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but in chrome, the load() function never runs. I've treid using the $.ajax function as well with the same result.

Any ideas why this is only affecting Chrome (v11.0)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there an error in the js console?

Comment: I'm checking the progress of a long running function. If I attach to a click event it works! Why won't it execute when attached the the form submit?

Comment: That sounds like what's happening. Is it only Chrome that doesn't allow Ajax requests during an http request?

Comment: I have a similar situation and I noticed that only the `ajax` functions are being "paused", not killed, upon a form submission - other `setInterval()` timers work just fine on the same page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you are actually submitting the form. I'm pretty sure this places the browser in a state of "hey, i'm waiting on a redirect from the server." If you really want to poll and update the page, you probably need to do

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

Just as a start. In this context, it works for me. Here, I even made you a pretty little JSFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/plukevdh/sRe4k/. If you need redirection once complete, you might add more data to the callback (json or something) so that you can check to see if `{status: 0-100 [percent], completed: true|false}` and if completed or status >= 100, just change the window.location.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code wrapped in a document ready check?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
});
```

If not, that may be why.

Comment: Yes and I can successfully execute other functions before the setInterval function too (like an alert).

Comment: OK - other cause could be permissions. Is this running locally? If so, Chrome doesn't allow AJAX calls to local files. Running on a webserver should be fine.